# Is this answer spam?

Tags: support, moderation, answers, flagging

This [answer](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/21250/21602) from March 28, 2020, which appears to be spam was brought to my attention in the Charcoal chat room when a user commented that their spam flag on that post had aged away. I have also flagged it as spam, but it seems that there has still not been any action other than downvoting.

This is the answer (redactions by me to avoid publicizing spam):

> It's  best to include surface shading in your design patent drawings to prevent a rejection by the US patent office. Design patents are all about the visual representation and understanding the overall structure. Often times the structure may be understood without the shading but why take the chance. Hire a good professional patent illustrator who will provide fully shaded design drawings in a format the uspto prefers. [company name redacted] out of [location redacted] provides a professional service [website redacted].

Is this spam? If so, could we get it handled? If not, why?

Answer (score 1):

This discussion is kind of moot since the answer has been deleted [by accumulating enough spam flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348357/how-can-a-site-without-moderators-start-the-process-to-get-elected-and-or-appoin#comment1165585_348357).

> Well, the meta effect worked. I just cast the last flag to nuke it now.

But that means, **yes, the answer was considered spam by SE users**.

However, as stated by [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348367/241919), this site does not have elected moderators.

> That said, Ask Patents is very different. We explicitly never sought out moderators there and I'm not aware of any plan to change that. It was mostly moderated by Robert, and will probably end up falling on another CM to just keep an eye on the flags queue.

Considering that CM (Community Manager; Stack Exchange staffs) might not have time to monitor this site, please report the spam to [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) (again), a chat room by [Charcoal group](https://charcoal-se.org/about) for cleaning spam out of Stack Exchange.